# Bash- loop through each character in a string to check for specific pattern

Tags: regex, string, bash, loops, character

So I need to check each character in a string- the input- to see if it matches/doesn't match a pattern.

In Codelish:

I'm guessing I'll have to use a for loop?

inside for loop there would be-

```
    for each character in string
    do (the following)
    if it doesn't contain one/more number
    echo it doesn't contain contain one/more number
    fi
    [then other conditions]
    done.
```

So what I'm trying to do is analyze each character in string and display error msg (for each condition) as output.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How can a character contain one _or more_ numbers?

Comment: oops, I meant a number (or alphabets in range). "if the character is not a number then do- something."

Comment: It would be useful if you made a start on this and indicated which part you were stuck with. Do you know how to write a `for` loop in bash? Do you know how to match a pattern? Are you willing to use a tool such as awk to do the job more effectively?

Comment: It would also be helpful if you could 1) be more explicit about this pattern you're looking for, 2) show us what your typical input data looks like, and 3) what output you expect. It's rarely efficient for a bash (or awk, perl or python) script to loop over a string character by character. It's generally _much_ better to use a properly-crafted regex (or something) to process whole strings at once.

Comment: Well, the general idea is to analyze input and display message if it matches/doesn't match a pattern. Like- if input is a passwd, does it contain one special character? Does it contain one/more upper case? Display message if it contains more than one special character. Specific- I'm looking for a command/s that will let me loop through each character of user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said above, looping over a string char by char is generally *not* a very efficient strategy. But here's one way to do that, using awk. The program below determines the character class of each character in each line of the input file. Please see the awk manual for the exact definitions of the [character classes](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Bracket-Expressions.html).

**CharTypes0.awk**

```awk
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

# Print the character class of each character in each input line
# Written by PM 2Ring 2014.10.02

BEGIN{numtypes = split("lower upper digit punct blank", types); FS = ""}

{
    for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)
        for (j=1; j<=numtypes; j++)
        {
            type = types[j]
            if ($i ~ "[[:" type ":]]")
            {
                printf "'%s': %s\n", $i, type
                break
            }
        }
}
```

You can run this program like this:

```bash
echo 'This is A $24 @test.' | awk -f CharTypes0.awk
```

**Output**

```bash
'T': upper
'h': lower
'i': lower
's': lower
' ': blank
'i': lower
's': lower
' ': blank
'A': upper
' ': blank
'$': punct
'2': digit
'4': digit
' ': blank
'@': punct
't': lower
'e': lower
's': lower
't': lower
'.': punct
```

Or you can get it to processs all the lines of one or more text files by naming them on the command line, eg:

```bash
awk -f CharTypes0.awk test1.txt test2.txt
```

.....

A rather more efficient version of this program could easily count the number of characters of each type in a whole word or line at once, rather than looping over each character.

---

**Edit**

For example,

**CountCharTypes0.awk**

```awk
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

# Count number of characters in each input line that match various classes
# Written by PM 2Ring 2014.10.01

BEGIN{numclasses = split("lower upper alpha digit alnum punct blank", classes)}

{
    printf "\nData:[%s] Length: %d\n", $0, length($0)
    for (i=1; i<=numclasses; i++)
    {
        class = classes[i]
        printf "%s %2d\n", class, gsub("[[:" class ":]]", "&")
    }
}
```

CharTypes0.awk

---

**Edit 2**

Here's a pure bash version of CharTypes:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Print the character class of each character in $1
# Written by PM 2Ring 2014.10.03
chartypes()
{
    types=(lower upper digit punct blank)

    string=$1

    for((i=0; i<${#string}; i++))    
    do
        ch=${string:i:1}
        for t in ${types[@]}
        do
            [[ $ch =~ [[:${t}:]] ]] &&
            { echo "[$ch] $t"; break; }
        done
    done
}

chartypes 'This is A $24 @test.'
```

Comment: What would be an efficient strategy? I just want a way to analyze a password and display msgs according to specifications.

Comment: Well, I'd probably do that in Python. But I'll add some more awk code to my answer that should give you ideas. Are you comfortable with writing in awk?

Comment: Well it's for an assignment, and we're using bash. Sure it could be done with awk, but we haven't covered awk utility yet. So a purely bash way (without awk) would be ideal  to analyze the string input/password. For personal preference I would use anything that works under bash but we haven't covered awk yet and some people have finished the assignment without using awk.

Comment: You could've mentioned that you couldn't use awk earlier, when Tom Fenech mentioned it, or when I posted my first example... But I'll add a pure bash version of that first example.

Comment: Ok, I think I can work with this. I get the logic now and can use it in my script. Thank you and chalking it down as the answer.

Comment: No worries, Bruce. I wouldn't mind seeing your script once it's working. Just add it to the bottom of your question. Or you can add it as an answer.