# Bash- dealing with commands as passing parameters

Tags: regex, bash, shell, parameters

So the thing is I've created a script for a password generator and a validator. It requires user to put in a password and it is checked for specifications. But the problem starts when the input contains the following- [, ], (, ), &, where I get either error messages or in the case of &- process starts in the background, prompting me to cancel running the script.

How do I somehow read the input as a string rather than string containing commands/other characters to give errors?

I can't really post the code here since it's a school project.

Comment: Can you at least post code the demonstrates the problem? That said, you are probably not quoting a parameter expansion.

Comment: Post an code what demonstrates the problem, not your school project.

Comment: Without seeing your code it is difficult to provide any help.

Comment: ok, so I type in ./passwordgen Jh7&  it returns [1] 9329. if it's ./passwordgen jdhh77( - it gives an error about '(' unexpected token. $variable=$1 is what I set, then I use the $variable to check for conditions.

Comment: `$variable="$1"` is wrong. Try `variable="$1"` . But it would make it **much** easier for the people who are trying to help you if you post some code. As jm666 said, we don't need to see your whole school project, just post a small example program that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the code I wrote in reply to [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26075341/bash-loop-through-each-character-in-a-string-to-check-for-specific-pattern), see that I quoted the arg to the `chartypes` function?

```
chartypes 'This is A $24 @test.'
```

When feeding it a string that's already stored in a variable, then as chepner said, you need to quote the variable using double quotes `"`, like this:

```
s='A string with various "special" chars: [ ] ( ) & !'
chartypes "$s"
```

You need to use double quotes here so that bash will expand `$s` properly. If you use single quotes `'`, then a literal `$s` would get passed to the function.

Comment: I tried with $variable="$1" and still it wouldn't work. And by the way I'm not trying to feed $1 to the function as I'm not using your chartype/variations. Just going with simple if-else to check for patterns in strings and it works perfectly except for the part I mentioned.

Comment: @BruceStrafford I just used my chartypes function as a convenient piece of example code that you're already familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

> so I type in ./passwordgen Jh7& it returns [1] 9329. if it's
>   ./passwordgen jdhh77( - it gives an error about '(' unexpected token.

Since the command line is interpreted clearly before your `passwordgen` script is started, nothing in your script can change this interpretation. Thus, it is imperative that you quote the script's argument if it contains characters special to the shell.

```
./passwordgen 'Jh7&'
./passwordgen 'jdhh77('
```